# Glossaries - Bold first letter of each word in \printglossaries

Tags: glossaries, bold, acronyms

I am trying to use the glossaries package to print a list of acronyms. Could someone please point me in the right direction to bold the first letter of each word in the printed glossary? Image below for clarification. 
[image]

In terms of a MWE (I know this is completely wrong but I thought I should try and include *some* attempt. I'm guessing the way in which \printglossaries presents the  argument in \newacronym[key-val list]{label}{abbrv}{long} needs to be redefined but I haven't a clue how)....

```
\documentclass{article}
% Load the package with the acronym option
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
% Generate the glossary
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\section*{Section with acronyms}
% Acronym definitions
\newacronym{utc}{UTC}{\textbf{C}oordinated Universal Time}
\newacronym{adt}{ADT}{Atlantic Daylight Time}
\newacronym{est}{EST}{Eastern Standard Time}
% Use the acronyms
\gls{utc} is 3 hours behind \gls{adt} and 10 hours ahead of \gls{est}.
\gls{utc} \gls{utc} 
%Print the glossary
\printglossaries
\small\hfill Created by http://texblog.org
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `glossaries` bundle also provides the [`mfirstuc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc) package, which provides the command `\capitalisewords`, which converts the first letter of each word to uppercase. This can be adapted so that instead of converting the letter to uppercase, it turns it bold instead. A new command can be created to do this:

```
\newrobustcmd{\bffirst}[1]{{\let\mfirstucMakeUppercase\textbf\capitalisewords{#1}}}
```

The extra pair of braces ensures that the change to `\mfirstucMakeUppercase` only has a local effect. (This is internally used by commands such as `\Gls`, so it's important to restore it.)

A new acronym style can then be defined that puts the description inside the argument of this new custom `\bffirst` command:

```
\newacronymstyle{bf-long-short}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-short}%
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%
  \renewcommand*{\GenericAcronymFields}{description={\bffirst{\the\glslongtok}}}%
}
```

This new style should be set before defining the acronyms:

```
\setacronymstyle{bf-long-short}
```

(If you get an "undefined control sequence" error for `\newacronymstyle`, then your version of `glossaries` is too old and needs to be updated.) Note that the [`glossaries` user manual advises against defining entries inside the `document` environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs) so I've moved `\newacronym` into the preamble in the modified example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load the package with the acronym option
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
% Generate the glossary
\makeglossaries

\newrobustcmd{\bffirst}[1]{{\let\mfirstucMakeUppercase\textbf\capitalisewords{#1}}}

\newacronymstyle{bf-long-short}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-short}%
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%
  \renewcommand*{\GenericAcronymFields}{description={\bffirst{\the\glslongtok}}}%
}

\setacronymstyle{bf-long-short}

% Acronym definitions
\newacronym{utc}{UTC}{Coordinated Universal Time}
\newacronym{adt}{ADT}{Atlantic Daylight Time}
\newacronym{est}{EST}{Eastern Standard Time}


\begin{document}
\section*{Section with acronyms}

% Use the acronyms
\gls{utc} is 3 hours behind \gls{adt} and 10 hours ahead of
\gls{est}.
\gls{utc} \gls{utc} 

%Print the glossary
\printglossaries
\small\hfill Created by http://texblog.org
\end{document}
```

This makes the first letter bold for each word of the description when displayed in the list of acronyms but doesn't change the normal behaviour in the main text.

**Edit:**

If you additionally load the `mfirstuc-english` package then `\capitalisewords` will ignore words like "a", "an", "of", "in". (If you open `mfirstuc-english.sty` in a text editor, you'll see which words have been defined using `\MFUnocap`.¹) Additional words can be added, for example,

```
\MFUnocap{as}
```

In the case where you have a letter taken from the middle of the word (rather than the initial letter) you will have to manually override the `description` for that case:

```
\newacronym[description={E\textbf{x}tensible \textbf{M}arkup \textbf{L}anguage}]{XML}{XML}{Extensible Markup Language}
```

Further information about `\capitalisewords`, `\MFUnocap` and related commands is available in the [`mfirstuc` user manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/mfirstuc-manual.html) which should be located in the same directory as the `glossaries` user manual.

---

¹ Disputed or context-dependent words (such as "up") aren't included by `mfirstuc-english` and need to be explicitly added using `\MFUnocap` if required.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for being so descriptive.

Comment: Although is there away to avoid boding the first letter of a words which might not be part of the acronym (of, as, in, etc.)? Similarly might it be possible to bold the first couple letters in a word?

Comment: If I could give you more points I would. Thank you.